# importing multiple images matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a set of 100 jpg images named consecutively and I want to add them up to get a single image. I have seen the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689639/how-to-average-multiple-images-in-matlab/5692384#5692384), but it does not run with me, what happened?

Here is the code:

```
im = imread('C:\Documents and Settings\1026175117_1.jpg');
for i = 2:10
im = imadd(im,imread(sprintf('C:\Documents and Settings\1026175117_%d.jpg',i)));
end
im = im/1000;
imshow(im,[]);
```

Here's the error message:

```
Error using ==> imread
Can't open file "C:" for reading;
you may not have read permission.
```

Answer (score 3):

Backslash is a special character for `sprintf()` and needs to be escaped. Either use "\\" instead of "\" or try constructing your file paths another way. `fullfile()` is a good way to do it, so you only have to use sprintf for the file name part. Also see `help sprintf`.

Comment: Hi John Colby, I substituted "\\" instead of "\". With this correction and ignoring the dividing operation I get a blank image

Comment: Hi John Colby, I substituted "\\" instead of "\". With this correction and ignoring the dividing operation because images are unit8 I get a blank rectangle. My images are interference fringes, so I don`t know what is the error.

Comment: Well, the blank is due to saturation, incrementing the i index turns clearer and clearer the resulting image. The dividing operation returns an error. any suggestions?

Comment: You can do `double(im)` and then it will let you do regular math to it.

Comment: Do that first and then just do `im = im + imread(...)` instead of `imadd`. (Because if you leave it as uint8 it will max out at 255)

Comment: Solved... sorry to bother you.

Comment: Solved... sorry to bother you. :S

Comment: @CarolinaRickenstorff Great! Glad it's working. You can click the "check" next to the answer so it'll show up as solved. Good luck!